# SQL error: Ambiguous column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have troubles with execution sql 
any time I execute it gives me an error Ambiguous column name 'salesYTD'
my statement is :

```
SELECT COUNTRYREGIONCODE, NAME, AVG(SALESQUOTA),AVG(BONUS), AVG(SALESYTD)  
FROM SALES.SALESPERSON SP
INNER JOIN SALES.SALESTERRITORY ST
ON SP.TERRITORYID = ST.TERRITORYID
GROUP BY NAME, COUNTRYREGIONCODE;
```

the name of that column is correct. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `SALESYTD` is in both tables.  I don't know which you want.

When you have more than one table in a query *always* qualify your column names.

```
SELECT ST.NAME, ST.COUNTRYREGIONCODE,
       AVG(SP.SALESQUOTA), AVG(SP.BONUS), AVG(SP.SALESYTD)  
FROM SALES.SALESPERSON SP INNER JOIN
     SALES.SALESTERRITORY ST
     ON SP.TERRITORYID = ST.TERRITORYID
GROUP BY ST.NAME, ST.COUNTRYREGIONCODE;
```

I'm just guessing where the columns come from.

Answer (score 0):

Does that column exist in more than one table?

If so, you should name the field like this:

```
SP.salesYTD
```

or

```
ST.salesYTD
```

Depending on what you want to show.

Good luck.